# JavaScript: How to fix an instance not being assigned property values properly

Tags: javascript, class, oop, object, properties

I create an instance of my `Piece` class and am trying to print out the value of the instance's `quantity`, but I keep getting undefined.

I look in the Google Chrome console, and `console.log(temp)` fine, but it appears to me like it wasn't assigned any property values.  (I believe it should show the properties and values if you click the drop-down arrow of the instance, correct?)

I also `console.log(length)` and `console.log(quantity)` and they print fine.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Parker Steel Program</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./main.css">
    <script src="./form.js"></script>
    <script src="./order.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Parker Steel Company</h1>
    <h2>New Order</h2>
    <form id="order-info">
        <label for="stock-length">Stock Length:</label>
        <input autofocus="true" id="stock-length" name="stock-length" required="true" type="number">
        <fieldset id="line1" name="line-1">
            <label for="line-1-length">Length: </label>
            <input id="line-1-length" name="line-1-length" required="true" type="number">
            <label for="line-1-quantity">Quantity: </label>
            <input id="line-1-quantity" name="line-1-quantity" required="true" type="number">
            <button onclick="removePurchaseLine('line1')" type="button">Remove</button>
        </fieldset>
        <button id="add-purchase-line" name="add-purchase-line" onclick="addPurchaseLine()" type="button">Add Purchase Line</button>
        <button onclick="getBestCuttingSequence()" type="button">Calculate</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

```
class Piece {
    constuctor(length, quantity) {
        this.length = length;
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }
}

function getBestCuttingSequence() {
    const stockLength = document.getElementById("stock-length").value;
    const pieces = getPieces();
}

function getPieces() {
    const pieces = []
    const numPurchaseLines = document.getElementsByTagName("fieldset").length; 

    for (let purchaseLine = 1; purchaseLine <= numPurchaseLines; purchaseLine++) {
        let length = document.getElementById(`line-${purchaseLine}-length`).value;
        let quantity = document.getElementById(`line-${purchaseLine}-quantity`).value;
        let temp = new Piece(length, quantity);
        console.log(temp.length);
    }

    return pieces;
}
```

Eventually, I will be pushing these instances to the `pieces` array, and then use them later.

My expected result would just be able to `console.log(temp.quantity)` and have it print the value.

It's currently printing undefined.

edit: changed property names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is little typo. `constuctor` is missing `r`. Change that it will work.

However you are adding properties to `this` without modifying you you could pass object and then `Object.assign`

```
class Piece {
    constructor(obj) {
        Object.assign(this,obj);
    }
}
```

And pass like this

```
let temp = new Piece({length, quantity});
```

Comment: I tried this and it still doesn't work.  Sorry, I forgot to edit that section of this code.  I will make the edit.

Comment: I can't believe I missed that.  Thanks for your help!